# Different behaviour of hexbin and histogram2d

Tags: python, matplotlib

What is the difference between hexbin and histogram2d?

```
f, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
ax1.hexbin(vradsel[0], distsel[0],gridsize=20,extent=-200,200,4,20],cmap=plt.cm.binary)
H, xedges, yedges =np.histogram2d(vradsel[0], distsel[0],bins=20,range=[[-200,200],[4,20]])
ax2.imshow(H, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.binary, aspect='auto',extent=[xedges[0],xedges[-1],yedges[0],yedges[-1]])
plt.show()
```

You can see that the histogram2d gives a -90 degree rotation. I know the data should be like the hexbin plot.

[image: Difference hexbin/histogram2d]

Comment: what if you compare `ax1.hexbin()` to `ax2.hist2d()`?

Comment: Yes, that was the difference. Those two are the same. I didnt now imshow() plotted something else then what I expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is not between the way the histograms are being calculated, but rather in the way you've plotted the histogram.  Your array `H` from `np.histogram` starts with the `4, -200` bin at the upper left of the array, but will be plotted depending on your default value of `origin`. You can control this using the `origin=lower` or `origin=upper` keywords in `plt.imshow`.

But `origin` just mirrors the image, so additionally you must remember that in images, the horizontal axis `x` comes first, and the vertical axis `y` comes second, the opposite of arrays, so you must also transpose `H` before plotting.

My recommendation is just to use `plt.hist2d()` instead, which will adjust the extent and orientation properly, as with `plt.hexbin`.  You can still access the result as with the numpy version: `H, x, y, im = ax.hist2d(...)` but it makes the plot automatically

---

```
a = np.random.rand(100)*400 - 200
b = np.random.rand(100)*16 + 4
a[:10] = -200
b[:10] = 4

f, ax = plt.subplots(3)

ax[0].hexbin(a, b, gridsize=20, extent=[-200,200,4,20], cmap=plt.cm.binary)

H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(a, b, bins=20, range=[[-200,200],[4,20]])
ax[1].imshow(H.T, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.binary, aspect='auto',
                extent=[xedges[0],xedges[-1],yedges[0],yedges[-1]], origin='lower')

# simplest and most reliable:
ax[2].hist2d(a, b, bins=20, range=[[-200,200],[4,20]], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
```

[image: hists]

Comment: Ahh, yes, I see now. Can I access the created array with `hist2d()`? Because I want to do one more operation (find the mean in every y-bin) with it. I think its better to use your #2 option (so with the `origin='lower'` flag). But thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Yes, it returns the information, but it also returns the matplotlib object as well, so use `H, xedges, yedeges, im = plt.hist2d(...)`  So I still recommend using `plt.hist2d` if you plan on plotting it anyway.

Comment: Thats why I got the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack` on my first try (without `im`).

Comment: H[0,2] H[1,2] H[2,2] \\
H[0,1] H[1,1] H[2,1] \\
H[0,0] H[1,0] H[2,0]
That is how it looks, right? (for a 3x3 bin). I checked it, but it just seems weird